# How to select a node referenced by an other node with XPath?

Tags: xpath, reference

I would like to select the purchase-node with the attribute pgnr, which has the value from another pgnr attribute, startig with "KEY", concatinated with "c".

Example:

```
<root>
<purchact hhid="xxx">
  <purchase pgnr="41">
   <purchvalues field_name="Number" field_value="1"/>
  </purchase>
  <purchase pgnr="KEY9802">
   <purchvalues field_name="Number" field_value="2"/>
  </purchase>
 <purchase pgnr="9802c">
   <purchvalues field_name="Number" field_value="3"/>
  </purchase>
 </purchact>
</root>
```

In this case, I am looking for the purchase-node with the pgnr-attribute "9802c", because the purchase-node with the pgnr-attribute starting with "KEY" has as the following characters "9802".

I tried

```
root/purchact/purchase[@pgnr=concat(substring-after(@pgnr, "KEY"), "c")]
```

but it doesn't work.

Could anybody help? Thanks so much!

Comment: Check my answer that it correctly selects all the elements you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
root/purchact/purchase[
    @pgnr = concat(
        substring-after(
            ../purchase[
                contains(@pgnr, 'KEY')
                ]/@pgnr,
            'KEY'
            )
        , 'c')
    ]
```

Comment: sorry, I am new here. Accepted, but couldn't upvote due to few reputation

Comment: @Flack: This would work only if the first 'KEY' starting `@pgnr` match some other, and only for this `purchase`. That's because implicit casting of node sets into singleton node sets.

Comment: @Alajandro. Agreed. It was easy to miss with this sample.

Answer (score 2):

This XPath expression:

```
root/purchact/purchase[
   @pgnr[substring(.,string-length()) = 'c']
][
   concat(
      'KEY',
      substring-before(
         @pgnr,
         'c'
      )
   ) = ../purchase/@pgnr
]
```

Meaning: *a `purchase` element having an `@pgnr` attribute ending with `'c'` and for wich there is at least one other `@pgnr` attribute belonging to a sibling `purchase` element and being equal to the concatenation of `'KEY'` and the string of the given `@pgnr` before `'c'`*.